# python multiprocessing/threading code exits early

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to create multiple processes which each call multiple threads.
I'm running the following code with python3.5

A simplified example of the problem looks like this:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import threading    

class dumb(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(dumb, self).__init__()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            print("hi")
            time.sleep(1)    

def test():
    for i in range(2):
        bar = dumb()
        bar.start()
def main():
    p = []
    for i in range(2):
        p.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=test))
    for i in p:
        i.start()
    for i in p:
        i.join()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I expect this code to print "hi" forever, but it prints exactly once for each thread in each process (4 times total).

When I remove the multiprocessing, the multi-threading works.

When I remove the multi-threading, the multiprocessing works.

The part that I think is the problem after I read the multiprocessing documentation:
The documentation for join states: "Block the calling thread until the process whose join() method is called terminates or until the optional timeout occurs."

If this was working as I expect it to, main would wait forever when trying to join.

I put try/except blocks around the while loop and didn't see any errors.

I have tried passing the "dumb" class a queue and passing exceptions through, but the queue stays empty.

Any tips on how to debug this would be greatly appreciated. My best guesses are

- The thread is exiting early (print statements after while loop were never hit though)
- Main exits and the processes are killed
- Join is working properly, but not the way I expect it to?

Any ideas?

Comment: Which OS and Python version?  I tried it just now under Python 3.5.2 (64-bit)  on Windows 10, and it worked fine (keeps printing `hi` "forever").

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and python version 3.5.1+, I'll try upgrading

Comment: Let's see whether someone on the same OS can reproduce - the code looks fine to me.  Please show the value of `sys.version` too.

Comment: sys.version:'3.5.1+ (default, Mar 30 2016, 22:46:26) \n[GCC 5.3.1 20160330]' Thanks for the quick reply, I really appreciate it

Comment: In case there's some screwup related to daemon threads, you could try `.join()`-ing the threads in `test()`, so that a worker process doesn't _try_ to exit before the threads complete.  They "should" wait for the threads regardless, but won't if the threads are mistakenly treated as daemons.

Comment: Because the parent process (test) returns after starting threads? I tried it on a windows machine (cyg-win) exited after printing 4 times.

Comment: adding the join in test worked! But I don't understand why it works on some versions/os and not others

Comment: Neither do I.  Python joins all non-daemon threads by itself as part of shutdown processing.  But daemon threads do _not_ prevent a process from exiting.  So my only guess is that your threads are mistakenly viewed as being daemons on your OS - which _would_ explain everything.  I can't pursue this, but encourage you to file a bug report:  http://bugs.python.org/

Comment: BTW, it's considered poor practice _not_ to `.join()` threads explicitly, so it's not too surprising if there's a bug here that simply went unnoticed.

Comment: Thanks for filing a bug report!  Here's a link to it:  http://bugs.python.org/issue27508

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolution:  the new bug was closed as a duplicate of http://bugs.python.org/issue18966

Alas, there's no simple, satisfying explanation "for why".  The cause is that `multiprocessing` arranges for worker processes to leave Python via calling `os._exit()` rather than the normal `sys.exit()`.  `os._exit()` skips all "normal" shutdown processing.  Part of what's skipped is `.join()`-ing non-daemon threads, so the process just vanishes *while* the threads are still running.

That should at least (according to me) be documented, or preferably changed.

In the meantime, the workaround - as you already know - is to explicitly `.join()` the threads yourself.

### ANOTHER WAY

Under Python 3.4 or later, you could also use `multiprocessing`'s `spawn` start method:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=spawn#contexts-and-start-methods

That causes worker processes to finish via `sys.exit(exitcode)`, which does all the normal shutdown processing (including `.join()`-ing non-daemon threads).

`spawn` is the *only* start method available on Windows, which explains why I had no problem running your original example.