# Why won't a Timer from threading work in Process from multiprocess?

Tags: python, timer, process, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am trying to run code within a `Process` from `multiprocessing`. The code uses `Timer` from `threading`. The timers never seem to be started. Why is this? I was able to reproduce the issue with the following code, which only prints the time once.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from threading import Timer
import time

def print_time_every_5_seconds():
    Timer(5,print_time_every_5_seconds).start()
    print(time.ctime())

start_process = Process(target=print_time_every_5_seconds)
start_process.start()
```

Output:
`Mon Jul 23 14:33:48 2018`

Comment: This may be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38356584/python-multiprocessing-threading-code-exits-early) problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `Process` is ending before the `Timer` event fires. If you can keep the `Process` alive, it will work. Here is one way to do that:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, SimpleQueue
from threading import Timer
import time
import functools

def print_time_every_5_seconds(que):
    while True:
        print(time.ctime())
        t = Timer(5,functools.partial(que.put, (None,))).start()
        que.get()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    que = SimpleQueue()
    start_process = Process(target=print_time_every_5_seconds, args=(que,))
    start_process.start()
```

Another way to do it is to set the start method to `spawn`, which causes started processes to wait for child threads instead of killing them as mentioned in the [Stackoverflow question mentioned by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38356584/python-multiprocessing-threading-code-exits-early). So here is the code that works using that method:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from threading import Timer
import time

def print_time_every_5_seconds():
    print(time.ctime())
    Timer(5,print_time_every_5_seconds).start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    start_process = mp.Process(target=print_time_every_5_seconds)
    start_process.start()
```

Comment: Then why when I print `threading.enumerate()` does there appear to be a thread waiting?

Comment: `[<_MainThread(MainThread, started 140735590110016)>, <_Timer(Thread-1, started 123145318416384)>]`, when printed after `time.ctime()`

Comment: So you are running that command in the started process before it terminates. That makes sense. When the process ends (for example, when the target method returns), then that process and all its threads are killed.

Comment: This is the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38356584/python-multiprocessing-threading-code-exits-early]